# Announcer Badge: Must share be within Stack Overflow or outside?

Tags: discussion

I've just had the Announcer badge for having shared a link to this post:

*[Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java/8885343#8885343)*

I do not remember having shared it within Stack Overflow, but I did on JavaCodeGeeks:

*[Printing arrays by hacking the JVM](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/03/printing-arrays-hacking-jvm.html)*

Could this be possible? If the answer is yes, how?